# JS receiving enumMap in json see fields as undefined

Tags: javascript, json, enum-map

I have REST ws which send json. Inside json there is enumMap (from java) and when I recieve json from REST, it looks like this:

```
{
map:{
KEY1:VALUE1,
KEY2:VALUE2}
}
```

when i try to do:

```
var something = map.KEY1;
console.log(something);
```

i see that something is undefined but when i do

```
console.log(map.KEY1);
```

than i see VALUE1

I don't see why it is not working. I tried many different set ups but in every one of them behaviour is the same or exception was thrown. Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you show more of the code surrounding your problem?

Comment: $http.get('/bcdg/rest/game')
                    .success(function (data) {
                        $scope.teamList = data;
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            var map = data[i].statsMap;
                            var val1 = map.VAL1;
                            console.log(val1);

Comment: Did you mean `map.KEY1` instead of `VAL1`? It's hard to help unless you give more code, what you have shown is very vague and has syntax errors so unless you post the whole code I don't know how much anyone can help.